# How do I manage that, regardless of which mobile device, there are AT LEAST 2 images next to each other?

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox

I created an online-shop with wordpress. (Have a look --> https://altdorfhittli.de/)

How is it possible to give the command via flex and css that on the mobile view there are ALWAYS 2 images next to each other and not to one, i.e. always one image below the other.

On front from a certain screen size, the images of the products and categories pictures are all below one another.
How do I manage that, regardless of which mobile device, there are AT LEAST 2 images next to each other?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

[image]remove height width properties from img tag and change this css -

```
@media (max-width: 599px)
.wp-block-column {
    flex-basis: 50%!important;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no change :(

Comment: @JulianBenz is thos how you want as shown in attchd screenshot?

Comment: correct! all good! it works! I also looked at it in the console, there is an additional plugin that annoys me, but I manage to solve it =) Thank you very much for the support!